# Make every text input in td be in a span

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, html-table

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet with the ability to format cell text, e.g. make it bold. I also need information boxes for each cell that can be shown, when information is available for that cell. I create the information box as a div in each td, and they are by default hidden.

The way I currently format each cell text is to apply a class to the td. This will format the text, but will also format the text in the information box, which I do not want.

I'be been looking at wrapping the text in the textNode in a span and then only apply the formatting class to that span. As long as there is text in the span, new text written in the cell will also be inside the span. But when all text in the cell is deleted, and new text is written, the new text is created in a new textNode instead of in the span, which is still there, though. This means, the new text written will not be formatted.

Any suggestions of the best solution to this problem? Is there a way to make inputs appear in a span by default or something like that?

Example of how my cells look:

```
<td id="cell-4-5" contenteditable="true">Test<div class="infoBox" contenteditable="false" style="display: none;"></div></td>
```

Comment: Create a custom function which returns you a newly-created `spanput`, which would be an input element wrapped in a span element.

Comment: I do not believe tds have input elements normally? But I tried with 

et input = $('<input>')
let span = $('<span>')
span.append(input)
cell.append(span)

this made the spreadsheet take forever to load, and it also looks weird.

Comment: Your title says there are inputs in the cells ... But now after you've edited the question, it appears, that you actually have editable cells. Add the span to the cell, and make the span editable instead of the cell itself.

Comment: Yeah, didn't explain it very well. But thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is obtainable using simple javascript. I have made a demonstration for you. Have a look.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#input-table td').forEach(single=>{
let ip = single.innerHTML;
let sp = "<span>"+ip+"</span>";
single.innerHTML = sp;
})
```

```html
<table id="input-table">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Input 1"></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Input 2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Input 3"></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Input 4"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I explained it badly. My cells / td doesn't have any input element. So when I write in the cells, the text is just in the textNode element.

Comment: My cells look like this, when I have wrote "test" in the cell: <td id="cell-4-5" contenteditable="true">Test<div class="infoBox" contenteditable="false" style="display: none;"></div></td>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how extensive your reformatting of a td might be but if it's just a few things, like bold/color etc which you know you may want to change, set the infoBox class to what you want want that to be. The greater specificity of the `td div.infoBox` will override any settings for td (including any style settings).

For example:

```
    td {
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
    /*etc;*/
    }
    
/* now ensure you have the formatting you want in the infoBox */
    
    td div.infoBox {
      color: black;
      font-weight: normal;
    /*etc*/
    }
```

```css
td {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td div.infoBox {
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="cell-4-5" contenteditable="true">Test<div class="infoBox" contenteditable="false" style="display: block;">info in div</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```